# How to return a 200 to a specific IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, ip

I've got some webhealth checks that mainly see if the server is still alive. At the moment when each get is performed it spins up an instance of the web app on the server. I'd like to just have apache2.4 rely with a 200 for the specific IP addresses that are used to run the health check.

Is that possible? How do you configure Apache to return a 200 (without doing anything else) when the GET comes from a specific set of IP addresses?

**Edit:**

To clarify why the question has been asked. The particular monitoring I'm concerned about is simple the monitoring of whether the server is up or down. The more detailed monitoring is managed by other methods and wouldn't be set to return 200.

The reason is that each web health check get (and there are multiple from around the world all at the same time) starts up the application stack and so produces an associated overhead. I want to avoid that overhead for what is simply a "are you alive" test.

Comment: What are you trying to check the health of? Apache the app or something else ?

Comment: Just whether the server is operational. Not necessarily whether the app is running. I've got other monitoring for that.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, that's possible. But that completely defeats the purpose of checking the health of the service...

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 1.2.3.4
RewriteRule . /path/to/some/static/file.html
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll look into that. This particular check is whether the server is up or down as opposed to whether the app itself is working.